# NSIS: Intaller crashes while staring c# window service

Tags: c#, nsis

I have created installer using NSIS simple service plugin. But the installer crashes and display message installer has stopped working.

Here is my code.

```
Name "TestInstaller"
OutFile "TestInstaller.exe"

ShowInstDetails show

#InstallDir '$PROGRAMFILES\TestService'

SetCompress Auto
SetDateSave On
SetDataBlockOptimize On
SetOverwrite on

Section
#SetOutPath $INSTDIR


# Start service
SimpleSC::StartService "TestService" 
Pop $0 ; returns an errorcode (<>0) otherwise success (0)
detailprint $0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleSC::StartService requires 3 parameters:

> SimpleSC::StartService [name_of_service] [arguments] [timeout]

Try `SimpleSC::StartService "TestService" '' 15`

Comment: What does timeout mean here?

Comment: I would guess it is the number of seconds the service manager is willing to wait for the service to start.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have to install your service before starting it 
using

```
SimpleSC::InstallService [name_of_service] [display_name] [service_type] [start_type]
```

[binary_path] [dependencies] [account] [password]